# PCB design components

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am designing a PCB but in my country it is hard to find components. As I am beginner, I am afraid to use similar components so I wanted to ask you.

[image]

I couldn't find this micro USB, I am using [this](https://www.robolinkmarket.com/usb-micro-b-5-pin-smd?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-Z2LgcXW8wIVC7h3Ch1YygWbEAQYCSABEgLAavD_BwE)        (probably this is okay.)

I couldn't find the NCP1117. I am thinking of using an LM1117 or AMS1117 SOT223 package. Are those okay? I worked with the LM1117 in TO-220 package before. If it is okay I will use it with 10uF and 100uF decoupling capacitors.
I found one NCP1117 but I don't know if is it [here](https://www.direnc.net/ncp1117st50t3g-1a-5v-smd-regulator-en?language=tr&h=550e52d9).

One more question, can I use the VBUS as 5V without add any resistors or capacitors?

Comment: As a beginner, you're doubting everything. The micro USB is a connector. "Micro USB is a standard so that part of the connector should always be OK, the part with the pads that are soldered to the PCB might be different. To know what you get: **study the datasheet**.

Comment: _"in my country it is hard to find components"_ Digikey, Mouser, Farnell and RS ship all over the world. Design with what you need, not what's locally available.

Comment: LM1117 and LM1117 are voltage regulators, they *should* be compatible but again **consult the datasheet**. Their footprint on the PCB could be (slightly) different. But since these devices are very standard (used everywhere) you are unlikely to have issues.

Comment: *If it is okay I will use it with 10uF and 100uF decoupling capacitors* Look in the **datasheet** of the component that you're going to use! You will have to learn to read the datasheet anyway. Don't try to understand everything all at once (you WILL go crazy), focus on what you understand and what you think is relevant.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you are right but I used to 220package with those capacitors. That's why I thought it is okay.

Comment: *One more question, can I use the VBUS as 5V without add any resistors or capacitors?* Yes but there will be a capacitor needed for the voltage regulator. Also realize that on the PCB you could make places for 5 capacitors but only place **one** or **zero**. Look on any PCB from a commercial device: lots and lots of empty places! They thought they needed something there, then later: no, we don't. So just left it unpopulated.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ooohh I see that's why they wrote DNF or NF right?

Comment: *they wrote DNF or NF right?* Yes or "NP" (not populated) I've also seen schematics where there's only an asterisk: *. It doesn't matter what it is, as long as it is clear what needs to be done.

Comment: @winny that's not very helpful. Depending on where the asker lives, shipping charges and charges for collecting tax and possibly duty on import might make it unreasonably expensive to buy from these vendors. And there's nothing wrong with learning how to tell what components can happily be substituted with others.

Comment: Thank you Bimpelrekkie, I read Datasheet [connectionlink](https://www.ti.com/product/LM1117?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=app-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe&utm_content=LM1117&ds_k=LM1117+Datasheet&DCM=yes&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkdONgNPW8wIVFdN3Ch1CmAMkEAAYASAAEgIqefD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) should I add resistor like this.

Comment: @nekomatic This is engineering, not scrapheap challenge.

Comment: @Tryingtogetsome "can I use the VBUS as 5V without add any resistors or capacitors?" - how much current will the circuit use? Will it be a steady current or have some bursts, like a device with a radio transmitter?

Comment: I will ise ethernet , adc module , RFID, I will use 5V 2A adapter but I news max 1A I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The [NCP1117](https://ca-en.alliedelec.com/m/d/e731b7f2c1ba10d65d2a8f4058dca813.pdf) datasheet allows for a ceramic output capacitor.

> A 10 uF ceramic or tantalum capacitor should be adequate for most
> applications

The [LM1117](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) specifies as follows:

> The ESR of the output capacitor should range between 0.3 Ω to 22 Ω.

Which rules out most ceramic capacitors. You can use a 10uF ceramic capacitor with a 1 ohm resistor in series.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have mentioned, do note that the USB standard limits C1 to 10uF maximum. If you increase it, your device may cause overcurrent protection to trigger in USB hosts or hubs, and turn your device off prematurely.